# method check login and password

Tags: java, hashmap

this method should compare login/password given by the user to the login/passord stored inthe database but this methode return always false the instruction braek don't work!!

```
public String loginPasswordCheck() {
    Connectionx cx = new Connectionx();
    Connection con = (Connection) cx.Connxion("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver","jdbc:mysql://localhost/kpidb", "root", "root");
    String log;
    String pwd;
    String checkaccess = "success";
    int profil_user;
    HashMap<String, String> mapLoginPWD = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> mapID_LoginPWD = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String sqlLogin;
    sqlLogin = "select PROFIL_USER_ID,login ,password from profil_user;";

    try {

        st = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sqlLogin);
        ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery();

        while (rs1.next()) {
            profil_user = rs1.getInt("PROFIL_USER_ID");
            profil_user_id = String.valueOf(profil_user);

            log = rs1.getString("login");
            pwd = rs1.getString("password");
            mapLoginPWD.put(log, pwd);
            mapID_LoginPWD.put(profil_user_id, mapLoginPWD);
            Iterator iteratorkeymaploginPWD = mapID_LoginPWD.keySet().iterator();

            while (iteratorkeymaploginPWD.hasNext()) {

                String myKeylog = (String) iteratorkeymaploginPWD.next();
                temp = mapID_LoginPWD.get(myKeylog);

                Iterator iteratortemp = temp.keySet().iterator();
                while (iteratortemp.hasNext()) {

                    String keyTemplog = (String) iteratortemp.next();
                    String valueTemppwd = temp.get(keyTemplog);
                    temp.clear();
                    mapID_LoginPWD.clear();
                    boolean bool = true;
                    if (!(this.login.equalsIgnoreCase(keyTemplog)) && !(this.password.equalsIgnoreCase(valueTemppwd)) && (bool)) {

                        bool = false;
                        checkaccess = "fail";
                    } else {
                        checkaccess = "success";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return checkaccess;
}
```

Comment: This should really return a boolean if your two cases are success and fail and you should do the returns right when you learn the checkaccess status not at the end of the method

Comment: @Grammin ,when I have added retrun checkaccess in the condition if ,the error missing return statement appear ,that's why I have did that

Comment: -1: Have you tried debugging this step-by-step, to find which line doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth ,yes I did ,the problem that the break don't work their,always the loop continue to browse all the rest of the rows ,that's why I have tried to add a boolean variable to prohibt the acces to the  condition if

Answer (score 0):

The logic is very difficult to follow, but I believe

```
boolean bool = true;
```

needs to come before

```
while (iteratortemp.hasNext()) {
```